# Is there any way to convert game assets into pixel art?

Tags: unity-game-engine, pixel, photoshop

Now I am  learning game development with Unity Engine .. but the problem is .. I'm a programmer .. I have zero experience in art and how to create game assets .. I have these huge ideas and I really want to make games .. so I took a course to learn how to draw and design but it doesn't work for me .. there are a lot of assets and characters to buy .. but they are different from each other .. so I came up with this idea of buying the assets and change them into pixel form .. to make them similar .. so I can build a game with them ..

the question now .. Is there any way in Photoshop or any other programs to convert those assets to pixel art?

All this About 2D Game Assets .. and 2D Games

Comment: Good pixel art will always require an experienced artist - there's no getting around that, you can either hire someone or try to find a 2D asset/sprite pack that fits your needs. If you're really set on trying to use 3D assets here, then one idea is to import them into your favourite 3D modeller program, apply a toon/stroked shader, and render out each frame you need (with the background being transparent). Regardless of which way you go, don't get too caught up with how it looks right now - if you're prototyping, using placeholder assets is good enough to demonstrate a proof of concept.

Comment: actually i mean 2D .. in every thing i wrote .. i have no interest in 3D games ..

Comment: In that case, my first and last sentence are still relevant - sure, you can easily pixelate an image with most image-processing programs, but you certainly won't want to do that for any production-level assets. Because you'll need to rely on edge detection to stroke the contours of the image (which can be...spotty), and often important details will be lost for any image that you need to rescale/pixelate like this. Just download a free 2D asset pack for placeholders so you can start coding, and consider professional alternatives down the road if you want to actually try releasing to the public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

The simple answer is no. There is no mystical algorithm that can take a game asset - photo or 3d model and simply turn it into a bitmap sprite. [image: Photo vs resuced size & palette]

In the example below, there is a photo of a lady dressed as Chun Li on the left. The right shows a version of the same photo, reduced in size and color (true color down to 16 colours). Notice the sprite version is missing an eye. That's the kind of detail that will be lost by any automated process. The detail in the dress and hands is also lacking.

I've worked as a pixel artist for many years and I understand your frustration. That's why I've answered your question) Many coders simply can't work without any art assets - because it looks crude or at best just doesn't look right. The best thing to do is work on the functionality of your code. Put in place some place-holder sprites (Purchase them from stock sites or similar). When the code is at a suitable point, seek out a pixel artist who'll help you fulfill your vision. That way you've already got a working version of your game, yur bitmap artist will just improve it's look many times over. I hope this helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. I too am an indie game developer and suck at art. However now I have an Artist on my team. But when I didn't I did a few different things:

1. [OpenGameArt.org](https://opengameart.org/)
   I love this place. People post art you can download and use. Lots of the work is also Free to use in commercial projects. Sometimes they even include the PSD file if you want to edit a little bit.
2. Simple games require simple art. A big part of the games I make are for mobile. In this I can make amazing games, and simple graphics. Like a colorful cube, or similar basic art.
3. People. I don't know if you're in school or are part of some community of sorts but often times there are many people who are good at these things but don't share it. Ask round and see if any one might wanna help on the side. Plus, more than one person means more that one brain.